# Question tagged with "-something" shows up as "not [something]" - why?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, server

Something odd happened to the tags of this question: [Automatic Garbage Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044795)

Here's a screenshot in case it gets edited or something:

[image: screenshot]

The tag in question is "-server" if you click edit.

Is this a feature, or a bug? If it's a feature, what does it do?

**Edit:** Just tried tagging this question with "-testing" and it stripped the "-". So I guess this is a bug.

Comment: It's been fixed since you posted this, indeed, but you can see the "not" in the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3044795/revisions). Looks like tag search logic leaked out!

Comment: Hah! Just as expected with a bug like this, if a question is tagged "not X", then it will basically count as not having that tag. So this question doesn't show up with a search for `[server]`, but it will show up in `[tagging] -[server]`!

Comment: Because @George edited it, the question now shows up on a `[server]` search and no longer shows up on `[tagging] -[server]`. It's basically a glorified empty space tag, it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ah, I think I finally see how this is happening.. `$_SERVER`

Comment: If you make it idiotproof, someone will build a better idiot.  I guess that applies to Regexes as well.

Comment: This still isn't working.

Comment: @george that wasn't the regex, actually, it was the fact that we silently convert _ to - in tags whenever we see it. Good old `String.Replace()`

Comment: Fix confirmed now.