# How does one get a single point of reputation on Meta?

Tags: support, reputation, meta, reputation-audit

According to my reputation report, my displayed reputation (4643) is 11 points too high over what it should be (4632). 10 of those points were an answer to a [question posed by BalusC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53708/something-in-moderation-tools-ui-fails-on-tags-prefixed-with-not) (10k only) which was a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53680/question-tagged-with-something-shows-up-as-not-something-why). The last point just showed up... I think today, really.

No math makes sense for what's highlighted at [the reputation FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work/7238#7238). Because questions are worth 10 on Meta, the only sources of odd numbers in reputation are the casting of downvotes, the reception of half-bounties, and having an answer accepted. The only way for a positive gain on a downvote cast is to undo the vote, which is not something post deletion will cause discrepancy, so that isn't the source. I have not answered any bounty questions at all, nevermind gotten the specific kind that awards an odd number on a half-award.

It can't be from an accepted answer, though. That would imply that I received 7 downvotes to cancel the other 14 reputation. I don't recall having posted anything THAT unpopular, but more importantly it's unrealistic. All of the downvotes I knowingly have received I can account for on the report, and because of the scanning interval that tracks my reputation, it can only feasibly have occurred in the 4 hours I slept last night. This means 7 downvotes distributed across posts that had 0/0 score initially and were subsequently deleted all in the span of 4 hours, *in addition to an accepted answer*. Possible, yes... but it's way too unrealistic.

This isn't the first time I've seen this off-by-one-point, either. Shortly after my 2k recalc, I ended up with 36 extra reputation, 35 of which were from a +2/+0 accepted answer... leaving yet another mysterious +1.

So I can't make any sense of this. What can possibly grant a +1 reputation on Meta?

It should be noted that my  displayed reputation this morning was the same as when I went to bed, 4622. And the extra +22/-1 since then, to reach 4643, I have recorded and observed personally, which means the +1 is not new, I actually lost an old point from long ago. So even further proof that accepted-answer-and-downvotes is unrealistic... but where did I get just +1 point?

Comment: Could you clarify? Is your current rep 11 points higher than what the report says, or does the report say your rep should be 11 points higher than what it is now?

Comment: My displayed reputation is 4643 as of this comment. Report says my actual reputation is 4632 as of this comment. Difference of 11, 10 of which is already accounted for in all points of time up to this morning. @Jon

Comment: Have you verified that the numbers in the rep report actually add up to the given total?

Comment: @Jon It'll take some time to verify fully, but for now my [temporally absent May 23-25th report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51131/days-with-a-net-loss-of-reputation-ruin-the-reputation-audit) is still accurate, so the +1 is from some point between then and now.

Comment: @Jon Confirmed: the numbers in the reputation report add up correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You also get odd amount of rep when you register to meta (+1). That is, your starting rep is +1 not 0.

Comment: hmm.. I think this is probably the answer.. we were all over thinking it

Comment: And +1 minus x still keeps one at +1. Likewise: +5 minus 10 gets one +1.

Comment: You can never lose the +1 for registration, definitely not from a recalc. You also can't get 2 of them, as I have. So no, this is NOT the answer. I still have my +1 from registration, so I still need something more feasible.

Answer (score 0):

That +11 difference doesn't have to be made up of a +10 and a +1 -- there are lots of other combinations.  Recall that one can gain/receive reputation in combinations of:

- +15: having an answer accepted
- +10: receiving an upvote on an answer
- +5: receiving an upvote on a question
- +2: accepting an answer
- -1: downvoting a post
- -2: receiving a downvote

Have you considered the possibility that the +11 comes from a (15 + -2 + -2) combination?

Comment: If the +11 comes from a 15-2-2 combination, what happened to the +10 on the answer to BalusC's question?