# Seemingly random reputation gain of 1

Tags: discussion, reputation

Every so often I appear to have a random reputation gain of 1. It just happened on math.stackexchange and I know that I didn't get downvoted by anyone in between. Any ideas of how that happens?

Comment: Now I understand, why random has so much rep. random, you lousy cheater!

Comment: Ha HA! I'm not the only one who gets [inexplicable gains of 1 reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54348/how-does-one-get-a-single-point-of-reputation-on-meta)!

Comment: So that's where it all goes.

Comment: The newest [Reputation FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) provides a number of sources for single point reputation changes, in case someone happens across this Q&A looking for an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you downvote a question or answer, that costs you 1 reputation. You will not get that reputation back unless you remove your downvote **or** the question/answer is deleted.

Comment: Probably a downvoted question/answer was deleted.

Comment: the same goes for downvoted answers, no? and don't forget this will not happen immediately but only after a rep-recalc

Comment: @Tobias, very true, however I was trying to keep it simple.

Answer (score 4):

Aside from undoing a downvote, if you just had a rep recalc, then deleted questions can cause small changes to your rep.  There are three things that confer odd rep:

- Question upvotes (+5, non-meta only)
- Accepted answers (+15)
- Downvotes issued (-1)

Undoing a downvote, or having a recalc done after the post you downvoted was deleted, will cause your reputation to change by exactly +1 if there are no other discrepancies.

You could also have a combination of the other factors.  For example, if you asked a question that received 1 upvote (+5) and 3 downvotes (-6) and subsequently deleted it, you'd get +1 on the recalc.

It could also be that something was *undeleted*, which does happen.  If you had an accepted answer on a question that was deleted (-15 on recalc), and two upvotes and downvotes (net score 0) on an answer that was *undeleted* (+16 on recalc), then that's also a change of +1.

I'm sure it sounds very improbable, but with enough users and posts it's bound to happen to someone.

If it still makes no sense, then check your [rep audit](https://math.stackexchange.com/reputation).

Answer (score 1):

There is one more reason.

When you hit the rep cap any upvotes will not have any effect on your reputation. However if you downvote a question and you loose -1 (200-1=199) from your reputation then if you get an upvote (within the same day), you will see a +1.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your recent page (click the at the top of the page envelope) in the "Reputation" section.

Answer (score 0):

Did you undo a downvote perhaps? Or a question you downvoted got deleted **and** your reputation was recalculated (far fetched, but possible)?