# Random reputation gain of 1

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation

This is in reference to *[Seemingly random reputation gain of 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58230/seemingly-random-reputation-gain-of-1)*.

**My Understanding**:

There is one more reason for a random reputation points gain of 1. It's obvious when you hit the reputation points cap any upvotes will not have any effect on your reputation points. However if you downvote a question and you lose 1 (200-1=199) from your reputation points and then if you get an upvote after that (within the same day), you will see a + 1.

If my understanding is correct then here is my

**Question**:

Why does it have to be that I get + 1 from the next upvote to fill the -1 gap? Why not from the already voted answers where it doesn't show any points?

[image]

My logic is that if I downvote say five questions after hitting the reputation points cap, I will not gain those five points till someone upvotes my question/answer. However, I might have 10 questions where the upvotes didn't count. So those five points are lost. If the system can automatically adjust the gaps with "one of those" 10 questions then the expert doesn't lose anything.

Something like this

[image]

One might say that it is the same thing, but it is not. We are depending on the future upvotes to fill the gap. What if there are no upvotes for the rest of the day?

Comment: @animuson: Thanks for the link. I'v seen it in the past & it is just my personal opinion that it's easier to search for stuff on SO than on meta. I spent aprox 10 minutes to search for similar questions but didn't find it. Because of my past experiences in meta, I even went to the extent of googling `+1 reputation changes stackoverflow` but I didn't get any of those links. When I was typing this question.. again in the suggested questions, I didn't find a match. In all I spent good 20-30 mins on this question.(searching, preparing,creating snapshots) I guess I should stop posting of meta...

Comment: Certainly not a problem. Searching *is* a lot harder on Meta. It actually took me about 10 minutes to re-find that question. The only reason I knew about it was because I had commented on it. No worries.